# Online Server Backup Storage

Tags: backup, rsync, online-storage

Hopefully someone here can help me.

I've been using a normal hosting account for my backups up until now. today they have told me I'm violating their terms and conditions. I thought it wouldn't be allowed but it's worked for the last 6 months so I just forgot about it.

I'm now looking for a real online backup storage service but can't seem to find one that does what I want.

I really only have one requirement, I must be able to rsync from my servers(linux) to the backup storage.

I would need a minimum of 5GB and wouldn't want to pay more than £7/$10 per month.

I've been looking at Amazon S3 but it looks like I can't use rsync with them without using an additional service. This seems very awkward and annoying for something so simple as rsync.

Does anyone know of a storage service that is usable for server backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [rsync.net](http://rsync.net) for a couple of years now. It's reasonably priced and offers lots of access methods.

Comment: Thanks I've seen them before but not really looked at them. I might give them a go as they do seem to offer their service at a good price.

Thanks for the tip!